# Attribute error when using simple plotting script

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a simple function in Python. I use the following code:

```
# lineplot.py
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
# Make an array of x values
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# Make an array of y values for each x value
y = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
# use pylab to plot x and y
pl.plot(x, y)
# show the plot on the screen
pl.show()
```

However, the last line in which I want to see the output results in the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_default_size'
```

Does anybody have any idea where I'm going wrong?

Full traceback of the error:

```
>>> pl.show()
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk.py", line 394,\    in expose_event
    self._render_figure(self._pixmap, w, h)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtkagg.py", line 75, in _render_figure
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 394, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 798, in draw
    func(*args)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 1946, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1017, in draw
    tick.draw(renderer)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 234, in draw
    self.label1.draw(renderer)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 526, in draw
    bbox, info = self._get_layout(renderer)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 300, in _get_layout
    ismath=False)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 180, in get_text_width_height_descent
    font = self._get_agg_font(prop)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 226, in _get_agg_font
    size = prop.get_size_in_points()
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 798, in get_size_in_points
    default_size = fontManager.get_default_size()
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_default_size'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk.py", line 394, in expose_event
    self._render_figure(self._pixmap, w, h)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtkagg.py", line 75, in _render_figure
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 394, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 798, in draw
    func(*args)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 1946, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1017, in draw
    tick.draw(renderer)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 234, in draw
    self.label1.draw(renderer)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 526, in draw
    bbox, info = self._get_layout(renderer)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 300, in _get_layout
    ismath=False)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 180, in get_text_width_height_descent
    font = self._get_agg_font(prop)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 226, in _get_agg_font
    size = prop.get_size_in_points()
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 798, in get_size_in_points
    default_size = fontManager.get_default_size()
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_default_size'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk.py", line 394, in expose_event
    self._render_figure(self._pixmap, w, h)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtkagg.py", line 75, in _render_figure
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 394, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 798, in draw
    func(*args)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 1946, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1017, in draw
    tick.draw(renderer)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 234, in draw
    self.label1.draw(renderer)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 526, in draw
    bbox, info = self._get_layout(renderer)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 300, in _get_layout
    ismath=False)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 180, in get_text_width_height_descent
    font = self._get_agg_font(prop)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 226, in _get_agg_font
    size = prop.get_size_in_points()
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 798, in get_size_in_points
    default_size = fontManager.get_default_size()
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_default_size'
```

Comment: What version of python and matplotlib are you using? The code ran fine here so there might be something else wrong.

Comment: Can you try using matplotlib directly instead of going through pylab? i.e. `import matplotlib.pyplot as pl` instead of `import pylab as pl`?

Comment: @M4rtini I'd say it's my backend, or whatever device i'm using to plot within. Version of python is 2.7. Matplotlib is version 1.0.1

Comment: @HannesOvrén - I still get the same error when i use matplotlib directly.

Comment: What backend do you use? You should get it from `python -c 'import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.backends.backend)'`

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano - i don't know how to find that out from the prompt. I am able to change it though. What is the default, since I haven't changed it to date?

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano - GTKAgg is my current backend.

Comment: One other thing: can you post the full traceback of the error?

Comment: Did you try to do other plots or this is the first time?

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano - Yes, this is the first time on this system.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44741/discussion-between-francesco-montesano-and-stars83clouds)

Comment: Then try a newer version (1.3.1) of `matplotlib`. If you don't know how to do it and you have sudo access to your system (I guess that you are on some linux), let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the version (1.0.1) of `matplotlib` used by the OP. Upgrading it solved the problem (as the discussion in chat clarified).

This is how we solved the problem (it should work on Linux):

1. Download the latest `matplotlib` tar file from the [download page](http://matplotlib.org/downloads.html)
2. extract the tar.gz archive
3. cd into the matplotlib directory
4. run

   ```
   python setup.py build
   ```

   If it fails complaining about some header file (e.g. `png.h`) install the relevant `-devel` packages from the system repository. For sure `python-devel` and `libpng12-devel` are needed
5. run

   ```
   python setup.py install --user
   ```

   It will install matplotlib in `$HOME/.local/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages`. This directory is loaded in the python path before any of the system wide ones. Plus there are no risks of messing up the system wide installations.